# Why the Publishing Settings --> Targets are all unchecked

Tags: publishing

[image: Publishing Targets are unchecked by default]

I have 5 publishing targets and when I need to publish any item, I need to go to

```
Publish --> Change --> Publishing Setting --> Targets
```

and I will see all Publishing Targets are unchecked. I need to manually check them every time.

Is there a way to let the system to check them by default?

Comment: Hi Jinglun, by default they are unchecked because it assumes that you intend the items to be published to all targets. Only check these here if you want to restrict to a specific target (or region). The publishing dialog provides you with an option to check/uncheck the targets and that will persist each time you attempt to publish.

Answer (score 1):

The Publishing Restriction is used per item and as Michael mention in his comment, by default all the publishing targets will not be checked. This is because Sitecore assumes that you will publish to all configured target databases.

The publish restriction allows you to decide whether this item should be publish to a specific target database but also

- You can decide which version can be publish
- When should Sitecore be allowed to publish the item

More information about Publish Restriction can be found [here](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/all-about-publishing-restrictions-in-the-sitecore-asp-net-cms).

If you have an item which should only be published to a specific target database, then, you should check the target database name in the Target Tab.

If you want to publish to a specific target database, upon clicking on the Publish button, it allows you to select to which database you want to publish (see screenshot below).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To have all checkboxes checked by default, Navigate to **Publishing** section of **About Us** item and check all targets in **Publishing targets** field as shown below and then if you open the dialog **Publishing Settings** dialog, it would render all checkboxes in checked state.

[image]

**Explanation -**

`Targets` tab in the `Publishing Settings` screen is rendered by file `\sitecore\shell\Applications\Content Manager\Dialogs\Set Publishing\Set Publishing.xml`

It uses `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.Dialogs.SetPublishing.SetPublishingForm` class from `Sitecore.Client` dll

and here below is the function to render that tab

```
/// <summary>Renders the target tab.</summary>
/// <param name="item">The item.</param>
private void RenderTargetTab(Item item)
{
  Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) item, nameof (item));
  Sitecore.Data.Fields.Field field = item.Fields[FieldIDs.PublishingTargets];
  if (field == null)
    return;
  Item obj = Context.ContentDatabase.Items["/sitecore/system/publishing targets"];
  if (obj == null)
    return;
  StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  string str1 = field.Value;
  foreach (Item child in obj.Children)
  {
    string str2 = str1.IndexOf(child.ID.ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCulture) >= 0 ? " checked=\"true\"" : string.Empty;
    string str3 = string.Empty;
    if (this.ReadOnly)
      str3 = " disabled=\"true\"";
    stringBuilder.Append("<input id=\"pb_" + ShortID.Encode(child.ID) + "\" name=\"pb_" + ShortID.Encode(child.ID) + "\" class=\"scRibbonCheckbox\" type=\"checkbox\"" + str2 + str3 + " style=\"vertical-align:middle\"/>");
    stringBuilder.Append(child.GetUIDisplayName());
    stringBuilder.Append("<br/>");
  }
  this.PublishingTargets.InnerHtml = stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

This function loops through all publishing targets and compares each target value on the current item's Publishing target field values to render the checkbox in a checked state.

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this, was going round in circles to understand why SiteCore unchecks all when I had already selected all targets. :D

- Site core defaults the publish to all targets and dont have to select a target.
- If a target is selected SiteCore will only publish to that selected target.
- if you publish with all targets selected, site core will publish to all, but uncheck all tartgets as it knows to push to all by default.

check point 6 on publishing targets on the SiteCore docs.
https://doc.sitecore.com/users/81/sitecore-experience-platform/en/publish-an-item-to-your-website.html